# Retrive specific record then goto next in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have database of employee of a single department where seniority list of sub department are maintained at sub office as per employee joining in department, first promotion date, then second (present) promotion date.

Now head department going to merge all employees of its sub departments on the basis of following criteria:

1. Oldest date promottee on present post within all sub dept will be placed on first serial no.
2. If, oldest date of promotees present promotion date equal to other employee present promotion date then his previous promotion date will be compared and oldest prev. promotion date promotee will be placed on first searial no.
3. If, previous promotion date also equal then date of birth will be consider for Seniority.

There is also a clause that

1. Shortlisted employee with above criteria should not placed above the senior employee of that particular sub department as per his sub department seniority number, from he/she belongs.

Column of each sub department data are as under:

1. Seniorty_No_subDept
2. Emp_Name
3. DOB
4. DateOfJoingInSubDept
5. DateOfFirstPromotion
6. DateOfSecondPromotion
7. SubDeptName

Merging Database columns are as under:

1. NewSeniorty_No
2. Emp_Name
3. DOB
4. DateOfJoingInSubDept
5. DateOfFirstPromotion
6. DateOfSecondPromotion
7. SubDeptName

I have not tried any code and confuse to choose recordset or sql or any other method to write the code.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well at least for this part:
"Now head department going to merge all employees of its sub departments on the basis of following criteria.. 1. Oldest date promottee on present post within all sub dept will be placed on first serial no. 2. If, oldest date of promotees present promotion date equal to other employee present promotion date then his previous promotion date will be compared and oldest prev. promotion date promotee will be placed on first searial no. 3. If, previous promotion date also equal then date of birth will be consider for Seniority."

Perhaps you could use an ORDER BY (sorting) clause in your SQL statement something like this:

ORDER BY DateOfSecondPromotion, DateOfFirstPromotion, DOB

Comment: I sorted the database on the basis of above mentioned criteria using Filter in table, but the problem is to sort also on the basis of employees sub department seniority position due to departmental clause i.e. "Shortlisted employee with above criteria should not placed above the senior employee of that particular sub department as per his sub department seniority number, from he/she belongs"

Comment: I want a code that insert the new merged seniority no in the column named : NewSeniorty_No in merged database table to each employee on the basis of department requirement as there are more then 2000 employees.